# How to turn buttons and reverses them with Meteor events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm working with the Meteor and the Bootstrap. I made a button that turns it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">Favoritar</button>
```

for this:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg active'>Favorito</button>
```

Now how do the reverse process?
My templates:

```
<template name="favoriteButton">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">Favoritar</button>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.favoriteButton.events({
"click .btn-default": function (event, template) {
  $(".btn-default").remove();
  $("body").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg active'>Favorito</button>");
  },
});
```

I try to do another event on the same template, but does not work. I try to create another template of events, but does not work. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a dynamic text for your button ?

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg active'>{{text}}</button>
```

And in your template:

```
var text = 'Favoritar';

Template.favoriteButton.onCreated(function() {
  Session.set(text , 'Favoritar');
});

Template.favoriteButton.helpers({

  text: function(){
    return Session.get(text);
  },

});
Template.favoriteButton.events({
  "click .btn-default": function (event, template) {
    SetSession(text, 'Favorito');
  }
});
```

**Update**

Or you could change your button with a simple condition:

```
{{#if isFavorite}}
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg active'>Favoritar</button>
{{else}}
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg active'>Favorito</button>
{{/if}}
```

In the template, something like this

```
Template.favoriteButton.helpers({

  isFavorite: function(){
    return Session.get(text) == "Favoritar"; // or better with a boolean variable
  },

});
```

Comment: Hello! It is an excellent idea. But I would like the button style/class change from "btn-default" to "btn-primary", or another way to customize.

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Kinda overkill here. You can also use helpers inside the HTML tag to get dynamic attributes.

Comment: You're welcome. As Kyll said, you could also add another helper to select the style inside the class attribute.