# Change button text in Meteor with JS

Tags: javascript, button, meteor, click, htmltext

My button on click show and hide div that contains comment section. Now I want to make him to change text on click. So, you click once and you can see comments but instead of 'Show comments' hes text now needs to be 'Hide comments'. I tried several solutions that I found on internet and a couple of solutions that were logic to me but it's not working. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920958/how-to-turn-buttons-and-reverses-them-with-meteor-events) too but it says that SetSession is not defined.

**Template:**

```
<template name="PrikažiMe">

<button class="PrikažiKomentar"> {{текст}} </button>

</template>
```

**JS**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {


  /*  Template.PrikažiMe.onCreated(function() {
        Session.set(текст , 'Прикажи коментаре');  // <---- This part makes like everything is unpublished
    }); */


    Template.PrikažiMe.events({
      'click .PrikažiKomentar': function(){

        if (document.getElementById(this._id).style.display == "none") 
            { document.getElementById(this._id).style.display = "inline-flex", SetSession (текст, 'Сакриј коментаре');}
        else {document.getElementById(this._id).style.display = "none", SetSession (текст, 'Прикажи коментаре'); }
      }, 
    });  

    Template.PrikažiMe.helpers({   
      текст: function(){
        return Session.get(текст);
      },
    });      
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out what was the problem. Hope this will help someone in the future. Look at the code:

**Template:**

```
<button class="PrikažiKomentar"> {{#if текст}}Сакриј коментаре {{else}} Прикажи коментаре {{/if}} </button>

</template>
```

**JS:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.PrikažiMe.onCreated(function PrikažiMeOnCreated() {
        this.текст = new ReactiveVar(false);
    }); 

    Template.PrikažiMe.events({
      'click .PrikažiKomentar': function(event, template){
        if (document.getElementById(this._id).style.display == "none") 
            { document.getElementById(this._id).style.display = "inline-flex", template.текст.set( true );}
        else {document.getElementById(this._id).style.display = "none", template.текст.set( false );}
      }, 
    });  

   Template.PrikažiMe.helpers({   
       текст: function() {
              return Template.instance().текст.get();
       },
    });      
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change HTML/CSS from JavaScript, instead handle that in your template.

Here's an example with untested code. It also relies on the package `reactive-var`.

```
<template name="t">
  <button id="b">{{#if isButtonActive}}Active!{{else}}Not active{{/if}}</button>
</template>
```

```
Template.t.onCreated(function(){
  this.isButtonActiveReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar(false)
})

Template.t.helpers({
  'isButtonActive': function(){
    return Template.instance().isButtonActiveReactiveVar.get()
  }
})

Template.t.events({
  'click #b': function(event, template){
    template.isButtonActiveReactiveVar.set(!template.isButtonActiveReactiveVar.get())
  }
})
```

Comment: I have error, template is not defined. No chance to do it with this.. There is no way to do it like i started above?

Comment: The @Peppe solution is better and follow the "Meteor way". Check if you well replace the "t" template name example by your "PrikažiMe". Advice, avoid weird accent on variable name...

Comment: @НиколаДашић, Yes, you can do it your way, but then I wouldn't use Meteor at all and only go with ordinary HTML and JS instead.

Comment: I just need hint for this, how to make button change text when it's clicked? Can I do that inside event?