# ReferenceError: template is not defined - Meteor?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I am making two different app's with Meteor. In first app, [witch you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538555/change-button-text-in-meteor-with-js), I am using `... template.текст.set( true ); ...` and everything is working fine. Now in second app I got error

> ReferenceError: template is not defined
>   So, what is the problem? I Checked, packages are same. 
>   Here is the code of second app:

```
Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
        this.TrenutniKorisnik = new ReactiveVar(true);
}); 



Template.PrijavaKorisnika.events({

    'submit .Prijava': function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        var korisnik = event.target.КорисничкоИме.value;
        var šifra = event.target.Лозинка.value;

        if (Korisnici.findOne({КорисничкоИме: korisnik, Шифра: šifra})) { template.TrenutniKorisnik.set( false )};



          event.target.КорисничкоИме.value = "";
          event.target.Лозинка.value = "";

     }
  });   



Template.body.helpers({   
       TrenutniKorisnik: function() {
              return Template.instance().TrenutniKorisnik.get();
       },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template instance is the second parameter in an event handler. Simply change this:

```
'submit .Prijava': function(event) {
```

to this:

```
'submit .Prijava': function(event, template) {
```

so `template` will be defined in the function body.

---

Once you solve that, however you'll find that `TrenutniKorisnik` isn't defined because it's on the `body` template and not the current template. One way to solve that is to use a file-scoped variable rather than a template one. Here's an example:

```
var TrenutniKorisnik = new ReactiveVar(true);

Template.PrijavaKorisnika.events({
  'submit .Prijava': function (event) {
    ...
    if (Korisnici.findOne({ КорисничкоИме: korisnik, Шифра: šifra })) {
      TrenutniKorisnik.set(false);
    }
    ...
  },
});

Template.body.helpers({
  TrenutniKorisnik: function () {
    return TrenutniKorisnik.get();
  },
});
```

Comment: TypeError: template.TrenutniKorisnik is undefined ... What is problem now?

Comment: `template` is a template instance - it refers to the current template. You defined `TrenutniKorisnik` on the `body`, which is not the current template. You could do a bunch of work to find the body template, but why not define `TrenutniKorisnik` as a file-scoped variable so you can avoid all of this?

Comment: So, to make `TrenutniKorisnik` as a new template in new file?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. You could define it in another file and import if you like (if using a newer version of meteor), or you can keep it file-scoped, or make it a global, or use a session variable. There are lots of options here.